# looping cell2mat to convert cell arrays to arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, cell-array

I have 4865 `1`-by-`1` cell arrays, I need to convert them to  into an ordinary array by `cell2mat`. When I run it I get the following error:

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

```
for i=1:4865,

    c(i) = cell2mat(A(i))

end
```

Comment: You have 4000 cell arrays or one cell array with 4000 elements? Is `A` a cell array with 4865 elements, each element consisting of a `1`-by-`1` cell array? What is in each of those cells?

Comment: you cannot convert a whole matrix to a single element of a vector

Comment: Can you show us what your initial cell array actually contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a whole matrix(which is in a cell) to one index

lets take the following example

```
>> cell_test ={[1 2 3;4 5 6],[1 2 3; 7 8 9]}

cell_test = 

    [2x3 double]    [2x3 double]
```

what you are doing is this

```
>> cell_test{1}

ans =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6

>> b(1) = cell_test{1}
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

One of the options is that you create a new variable name for every new index through `eval()` like ofcourse there are many other options

```
>> i = 1

i =

     1

eval(['B_',num2str(i)  ,'=cell_test{i}'])

B_1 =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

Update : structure method `B(i).data = =cell_test{i}`

Comment: Please don't recommend using `eval` for this sort of thing. Wait for the OP to clarify what they want.

Comment: It was just a suggestion , if you recommend i will update and add a saving to structure method

Comment: Thank you Umar, it worked for me. Could you please show me the saving to structure method?

Comment: Great. I have updated my answer with structure method , please accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: You can dynamically add in fields by constructing strings without having to use `eval`. Avoid using it as it is bad practice.